# How to avoid apache allow download certain files?

Tags: permissions, security, apache-httpd

How to avoid apache allow download certain files? (for example .py and .sh)

I want to avoid files to be served and downloaded like

```
www.site.com/file.sh
www.site.com/file.py
```

but I've tried to do this

```
<Files ~ "^\.sh">
   Order deny,allow
   deny from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "^\.py">
   Order deny,allow
   deny from all
</Files>
```

also this

```
<FilesMatch "\.(sh|py)$">
   Order deny,allow
   deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Nothings seems to work, I've tried to put the file in

> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

also

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Nothing works, **apache still let me download the files**.

Comment: Of course, this just means someone will simply rename the files with a `.txt` extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your file match clauses seem to be incorrect.

```
<Files ~ "^\.py">
```

will match files whose names will *start* with characters `.py`. You'll want

```
<Files ~ "\.py$">
```

instead.

But your `FilesMatch` regular expression looks correct. So maybe the problem lies elsewhere. Perhaps your Apache uses the new-style access control directives only?

Try replacing the old-style

```
Order deny,allow
deny from all
```

with the new-style equivalent:

```
Require all denied
```

Comment: Done!, the <Files> fix, fixed the issue, in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: FilesMatch doesn't seem to work in this apache v 2.2